# Service crashes with exception: Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, windows-services

For some reason service crashes with message in the event viewer saying "Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll" no any other useful information. It kills the whole process. We can not find what causes this problem and can't catch this exception. We are not referencing this module in our source.
Service is running on Windows 7 64 bit .NET 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search shows this to be a common error for a variety of applications. It also reveals this is a common underlying library.

I have a couple of potential suggestions, as a quick search revealed no firm answer that matches your issue exactly.

One possibility is this library is unregistered in Windows. This assumes it is COM based, of course. I don't think this is the first approach, but it is a possibility.

Another is a 64 bit issue. The most likely cause here would be a 32 bit service on a 64 bit OS. One potential method is to set up the service as 64 bit; the other would be ensure the DLL in question is being usable by WOW. This would most likely be plopping a copy of the DLL in SysWOW64.

Comment: MSVCR100.dll is the Microsoft VisualStudio C runtime library, the most basic library of any C/C++ program. It's not a COM component and doesn't need to be registered.

Comment: It would have been nice if the person who posted this question, and accepted this answer, had specified which part of the answer was applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me: I had a .NET app that monitored (check if alive, start if dead, kill if too much mem used) a C++ app. The C++ app was unable to start properly and that error was all above the EventLog.

Recompiling the .NET app in .NET 4.0 (was 2.0) solved the issue